# linker error while osg build osgviewer

Tags: linker, slackware

I am trying to build osg 14.0 on slackware 14.0 from source. I get linker error while creating executable files from osgviewer:

```
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/osgviewer
../../lib/libosg.so.3.0.1: undefined reference to     `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_transfer(std::__detail::_List_node_base*,     std::__detail::_List_node_base*)'
../../lib/libosg.so.3.0.1: undefined reference to     `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_hook(std::__detail::_List_node_base*)'
../../lib/libosg.so.3.0.1: undefined reference to     `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_unhook()'
../../lib/libosgDB.so.3.0.1: undefined reference to         `std::__detail::_List_node_base::swap(std::__detail::_List_node_base&,              std::__detail::_List_node_base&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/osgviewer] Error 1
make[1]: *** [applications/osgviewer/CMakeFiles/application_osgviewer.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This is ld.so.conf

```
/usr/local/lib
/usr/i486-slackware-linux/lib
/usr/lib/seamonkey
/usr/lib
```

Do you know where the problem could be ?

Thank you.

Comment: It turns out that my gcc was broken. I did
    `slackpkg reinstall gcc`
and it worked nicely.